# Community♦による質問の上げ行為は必要なのか？

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求

最近アクティブな質問のページを見てて思ったのですが、Community♦に上げられた記事が多すぎないでしょうか？

最近アクティブな質問 - スタック・オーバーフロー  
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

（この質問を行う直前に）ざっと数えたところ、過去24時間で質問・回答・更新された質問が35件で、そのうちCommunity♦に上げられたものが12件でした。（1時間に1回では無くなった？）

これは個人の感想ですが、『最近アクティブな質問をみたい』と思ってページを開いたときに、34%がノイズというのは少し多すぎるように思われます。

もう少し日本のスタック・オーバーフローが活発になれば別でしょうが、少なくとも現在のスタック・オーバーフローには、Community♦による上げ行為は不要なのでは無いでしょうか？

そもそも、最近アクティブな質問を気にしている人間なんて少数派なのかもしれませんが・・・　それならそれで、結局、Community♦による上げ行為は不要なように思われます。

参考になりそうなスクリーンショットが撮れたので追加しておきます。

[image: Community♦無双]

Comment: 活発になれば別とありますが、つまり今の投稿・編集の頻度に対して「上げ」られた質問が多すぎるからもっと減らしてほしいということでしょうか。それともこのシステム自体が不要と思われるのでしょうか。

Comment: 今、パッと思いついた数字で言うと、アクティブな質問10件につき、故意に（？）上げられたのが1件ぐらいなら、問題ないような気がします。つまり、頻度を下げるだけでも良いかと。そもそも『Community♦による上げ行為にメリットがあるのか？』については、よくわかりません。無くても誰も困らないような気もします。

Comment: 過去の質問を定期的にリマインドする仕組み自体は読み物サイトとしてもvoteを活発にするためにも有益だと思うのですが…少数派？ 確かに頻度が過剰すぎるとは思います

Answer (score 8, accepted):

編集②

開発者がこれをメタに適用しましたので、まだメインサイトでは発生しています。開発者に聞こうとしましたが、unaristの回答が＋６にもなっていますし、質問との反対意見になるため、メインサイトに適用する前にもっと討議が必要ではないかなと思ってきました。

現在の頻度は1時間毎に１つの質問を上げます。頻度を変えることもできますし、もちろんゼロにすることも可能ですが、未回答に質問はメインページから出たら終わりにすればベストですか？

---

開発者と確認した結果、無効にすることができます。

現在の設定はプラス票が付いている回答がない質問をフロントページに定期的に戻します。

今からCommunityユーザーはそれをしません。後日復活することは可能です。

---

開発者と相談してみます（僕もノイズになる可能性が多いと思っています）。

英語版では、オフピークに投稿したら（アメリカの夜中・週末等）誰もその投稿を見ない可能性が高かったです。月曜日になると投稿数が増えて、週末の投稿に回答がなかったら、フロントページから外れたので、その投稿を見落とさないようにCommunityがもう一回フロントページに上げます。

日本語版では時差があまりないので、この機能をオフしても問題ないが、投稿数が増えたら再びオンにしていいんじゃないかと思います。もし簡単な変更なら、すぐ実施したいと思います。

（反対の意見があれば、ご教示ください）

Comment: 対応ありがとうございます。1時間に1回の上げで問題ないくらい、日本のスタック・オーバーフローが活発になってくれれば良いですね。逆に、本家みたいに非常に活発になると、それはそれでCommunity♦の上げは効果がなさそうですが・・・

Comment: 無効になってますか？まだ動いてるように見えます

Comment: @suzukis 回答を編集しました。

Comment: 『頻度が多すぎるのは問題』と言う点では概ね一致してるようですし、とりあえず頻度を下げてみてはどうでしょうか？　個人的には、3時間に1件の上げぐらいで良いのかな、と思います。

Comment: ところで、全く回答されていない質問はbump対象なんでしょうか。そう思って自分の回答にも書いていますが、対象にならないという話もMetaSEにはあるようで・・・ http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217884/286934

Comment: @unarist 回答があっても、プラス票がされなかったら「未回答」として考えています。正しかったら、他ユーザーがプラス票でその回答を認めるコンセプトです。問題はプラス票は少なすぎかな？

Comment: @jmac スコア0の回答はそうですが、回答が1件も付いていない質問はbumpされるのですか？

Comment: @unarist 回答付きのスコアゼロのみの質問をbumpします（[参考](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/209637)）。だから、回答が付いている＝回答可能な質問です。スコアゼロ＝回答がまだ信用できるかどうか分からないので、投票のためにbumpします。３０日間アクティビティがない場合のみ。

Comment: See.Kuさんやsuzukisさんの意見を踏まえ、メインサイトでは3時間に1回としてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 9):

Communityユーザーが上げる質問は、回答が全くないか、プラス投票も承認もされていない、かつクローズされてもいない、いわば未解決の質問です。検索でもしない限り人の目につかないこれらの質問について、時々存在を思い出させてくれるようなものだと思っています。

新着順（そうでなくとも最近見かけてる）かスコア順（難しい質問がずっと居座っている）しかない[未回答の質問リスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)と比べ、ランダムに掘り返してくれるのは新たな発見があります。

また頻繁に訪れるユーザーからすれば同じ質問が何度も現れて邪魔かもしれませんが、たまにしか来ない人や初めて来た人にとっては、過去の未回答質問も初めて目にするものかもしれません。

というわけで、（頻度はともかく）このシステムに一定の意義はあるかと思います。

Comment: 「プラス投票も承認もされていない」というのは回答についてですか？1つでも+1になってる回答があれば「上げ」る対象にはならないということでしょうか。

Comment: @suzukis はい、そうです。 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/286934

Answer (score 4):

現在下記の対策を実施しています：

1. 質問を投稿していない時に質問を上げない
2. フロントページに上げた投稿が多ければ、上げない

現在の設定は1時間何問を上げる設定しかないです。当サイトは日本中心ですので、特に日本の夜中で投稿が少ないです（開発者も寝るらしい）。週末に投稿はありますが、頻度は平日と比べて少ないので、月曜日にフロントページを見ると、3割〜4割の投稿はCommunityで上げました。

この二つの設定を追加することで、投稿が上げても、多くは感じないようになると思います。

#### 追記

他のサイトの数字を見ると、当サイトでの上げる対象質問率は低いですが、ほかのサイトと違って当サイトのユーザーが一つの時間帯に集中しているため、朝に起きると複数の古い質問が待っていると気持ち的に古い回答していない質問が多いと感じているだけです。（もちろん、投票がない回答を投票してください！）

Answer (score 2):

この機能によって回答に結びついた数がわかればいいのですが難しいですかね。

確かに現状では頻度が多すぎるように思います。しょっちゅう同じ質問を見るような印象があります。とは言っても見たことがない質問に気付くこともあるので、全く無いのもどうかと思います。全く個人的な感覚ですが、半分か1/3ぐらいでいいかなぁ。

ところで私はこれ勘違いしてたのですが、回答にプラス票が入ってたら上がってこないのですね。

回答がついてるが承認されてないような質問については適切な回答と判断できればプラス票を入れるように気をつけるようにしてみたいと思います。